# postcode in woocommerce cart page wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

i want change the delivery charge based on the postcodein cart page.So, i put one text box in cart page.The delivery charge should change when i change the postcode in that text field.Generally the postcode is in checkout page,so i dont have the clear idea about that.Now i want the postcode functionality in cart page in woocommerce.If anybody have an idea,pls suggest me!

```
public function get_shipping_packages() {
        global $woocommerce;

        // Packages array for storing 'carts'
        $packages = array();

        $packages[0]['contents']                 = $this->get_cart();       // Items in the package
        $packages[0]['contents_cost']            = 0;                       // Cost of items in the package, set below
        $packages[0]['applied_coupons']          = $this->applied_coupons;  // Applied coupons - some, like free shipping, affect costs
        $packages[0]['destination']['country']   = $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country();
        $packages[0]['destination']['state']     = $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_state();
        $packages[0]['destination']['postcode']  = $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_postcode();
        $packages[0]['destination']['city']      = $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_city();
        $packages[0]['destination']['address']   = $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_address();
        $packages[0]['destination']['address_2'] = $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_address_2();

        foreach ( $this->get_cart() as $item )
            if ( $item['data']->needs_shipping() )
                $packages[0]['contents_cost'] += $item['line_total'];

        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages', $packages );
    }
```

I have an text box in cart page.when i change the postcode ,the delivery charges and all the totals should change according to that.I dont know where i have to work in woocommerce files.

Comment: woocommerce has post code field, you don't need to create your own field, you can accomplish what you want using ajax + session,

Comment: Ya but i want a field to change the postcode in cart page by the user.they dont need to change it in the checkout page.